# can we change the .rdb format of mesa sqlite database to .db?

Tags: database, file-format, mesa

I have created a database in mesa sqlite software which creates a .rdb format DB in default.
I want a .db file.
can I change the .rdb format to .db?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Of course you cannot just change the format of the database file, then sqlite will not be able to read it. Or are you asking if you can change the file name?

Comment: No, I do not wish to change the file name. I want to change the extension(file format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used mesasqlite, but it seems you could just rename your db file to any name/extension you want.

Comment: mesa does not allow to change the extension even while creating it. So, i was wondering if there is a work around for this problem

Comment: You could change extension with any other tool you like, like your favourite file manager.